# Auto log out from devices

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a RestAPI which will hit to authenticate the user. This api is to android they hit this api to allow user to login to our app

My requirement is this.1) If user has cell phone say xyz phone with IMEI "xyzz1234". Now if he tries to log in from his 2nd phone than he should not be allowed to login from 2nd phone. He should log out automatically from abc device.

As i am using ionicv1 framework for mobile applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the deviceID in your database once the user Sign in on another device.
In your signIN API, validate your deviceID.
For the case of login state saved in your app, you can hit an API at your dashboard on startup which can make the person logout.

This could be one possible approach :)